# Need help with reinstalling grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, boot-repair

so I installed windows 7 after installing ubuntu, and as you may already know I can't log back into ubuntu.

I tried running boot-repair but it seems to be stuck on purging the kernels (I left it for quite a couple of hours, but still no result).

I tried manually re-installing grub via terminal (using live usb), and I actually managed to load the grub menu but could not see ubuntu on the list (just windows 7 and some memory tests).

Here is a link to th BootInfo summary from boot-repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10686106/

Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggested actions at the bottom of the Boot-Repair script actually look like the right thing to do here, but you said it got stuck, so we'll need to look for a manual solution.

The Grub boot loader appears to be alive and well, but the boot menu has no entries, so you'll need to follow [the instructions of this answer](/a/88432/175814) to repopulate it.

Check the output of `update-grub`, which should contain

- 1 entry for each Linux kernel of your Ubuntu installation (possibly more),
- 1 entry for Memtest86+, and
- ≥1 entries for Windows.

If it doesn't or you still can't boot, please post that output and include the content of `<SDA1_MOUNTPOINT>/boot/grub/grub.cfg` for further investigation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I actually tried using the advanced options of boot repair (instead of the recommended repair) and unticked purge and reinstall kernels and it seems to have reinstalled grub properly and now I can see both windows 7 and Ubuntu. So all's good!